# Prevent navigation on anchor that has routerLink

Tags: javascript, angular, anchor, preventdefault

In my markup, there is `[routerLink]="(onLink | async).linkURL"`

And when its there, I'm unable to stop the navigation from happening when user clicks it.

If I remove `[routerLink]="(onLink | async).linkURL"`, the navigation is stopped as expected.

Is there a way I can stop the navigation here? I'm unable to remove `[routerLink]="(onLink | async).linkURL"` from the markup.

My js below is not run in the angular context btw, its plain js.

Html ..

```
<div>
    <a id="myLink" [routerLink]="(onLink | async).linkURL">My link</a>
</div>
```

Javascript ..

```
document.getElementById('myLink').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log('click');
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Is this Angular (2/4/5) or AngularJS?

Comment: Why would you place a `routerLink` on an anchor element, if you do not want navigation?

Comment: oh yeah, its angular 4 .. @ArmenVardanyan preventing navigation will only happen in certain cases

Comment: AngularJS? The `[]` binding syntax is clearly Angular. not AngularJS (which is referring to 1.x versions)

Comment: So maybe share the cases?

Comment: @ArmenVardanyan not sure how that would help, can you just assume there is a toggle in the UI that disables the naivgation for the anchor

Comment: @ArmenVardanyan (_it was tagged with_ `[angularjs]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's standard way to enable/disable navigation from a given route is to implement a [CanDeactivate route guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards). Similarly, you can implement a `CanActivate` route guard to enable/disable navigation to a given route.

An example of a `CanDeactivate` route guard is shown in **[this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-ukhrl7)**, where the state of a check box allows or prevents navigation from the "Home" page.

In app.module:

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
import { DeactivateGuard } from './views/home/deactivate-guard';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    AppRoutingModule, 
    ... 
  ],
  providers: [
    DeactivateGuard
  ],
  ...
})
```

In app.routing.module:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DeactivateGuard } from './views/home/deactivate-guard';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      ...
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeViewComponent,
        canDeactivate: [DeactivateGuard]
      },
      ...
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
  ],
  ... 
})
```

In home/deactivate-guard:

```
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeViewComponent } from './home.component';

export class DeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<HomeViewComponent> {

  canDeactivate(component: HomeViewComponent) {
    return component.canDeactivate();
  }
}
```

In home.component:

```
export class HomeViewComponent {

  allowNavigation = true;

  canDeactivate() {
    return this.allowNavigation;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is an overkill for such a simple task. A simple conditional if check prior to navigation will do. This suggestion feels like killing an ant with Thor's Hammer. Because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot remove the `[routerLink]` and replace it with a `(click)` listener to handle the logic in a class method, maybe give this a try. In your component class:

```
shouldNavigate: boolean = false; // indicated whether it is possible to navigate
constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

And inside the HTML template:

```
<a [routerLink]="shouldNavigate ? (onLink | async).linkURL : route.url">My link</a>
```

In Angular, if anchor points to the same url the user is now on, the navigation will not occur, so depending on the circumstances, change the url to the current page's url and be done with it.

Other options: you can write a directive that handles navigation or so. Let me know if this answer is not satisfying enough, so I may pick up another approach. This one is by far the laziest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this navigation logic on the component. You can add (click)=" method()" method on
the anchor tag and add logic on the component method. I faced this issue and added logic on the component and used return in case I want to stop navigation.

I used router in component.
this.router.navigate([]);

Answer (score 0):

In your comments under the original question you ask us to "... assume there is a toggle in the UI that disables [the navigation]".

A method I've found is to disable pointer events using css. You get to keep your `routerLink` and `routerLinkActive` css class logic, but your users won't see the navigation link down in the browser status bar, and they won't be able to click the link to navigate.

```html
<div>
  <a id="myLink"
     [routerLink]="(onLink | async).linkURL"
     [routerLinkActive]="active"
     [style.pointer-events]="toggledOn ? 'auto' : 'none'">
    My link
  </a>
</div>
```